# Using Content Block of type Layout in a custom HTML template for SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template, content, dynamic-content

I am working on an email template that uses content blocks. The content blocks are retrieve using some ampscript that loops through a JSON string of contentBlocksIDs.

I also wanted to use content Blocks of type layout. To reduce the number of blocks being called and make the blocks easily updatable in SFMC.

However when retrieving contentblocks of type layout. I get additional tags showing up in the HTML e.g.

{{.slot gs2t3g2cwm6}}{{.block vbch6gq6y1d imageblock}}

Is there anyway to remove these tags when using layouts outside of the email builder.

My current only other option would be to rebuild each layout as a HTML block.

Thanks